# Why I get this JavaScript error with jQuery Validate?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I use jquery.unobtrusive and jquery.validate libraries in asp.net mvc 5 project to validate user registration on client side.

on browser I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parents(...).andSelf is not a function
    at Object.parse (jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:211)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:392)
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.1.1.js:3570)
    at process (jquery-3.1.1.js:3638)
```

I use jquery 3.1.1 in my project.It seem to be versions problems.

Any idea how can I solve it?

Answer (score 21):

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parents(...).**andSelf is not a function**

[Read the jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/andself/).

> "I use jquery 3.1.1 in my project."

The `.andSelf()` method was removed from jQuery version 3

It was an alias for [the `.addBack()` method](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/), which should be used instead.

Answer (score 13):

Like @Sparky said, this is because the Unobtrusive JS files obtained from NuGet (if you create an app using File->New in Visual Studio) uses the deprecated andSelf() function.

To resolve, get the latest versions of

jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js 
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

from

https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/tree/master/dist

and replace the ones in your project. Or Download / Update exiting plugin from nuget.

After Replacing 
Make sure you clear your browser cache. (Control + F5 if you are using chrome)